# Exceptions are not cought by custom TelemetryProcesor in AppInsights in isolated (out-of-process) Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, .net-5

Recently we moved from *in-process* Azure Functions to *out-of-process* Functions (aka *isolated* Functions, aka Functions based on *DotNet Worker*, aka `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = dotnet-isolated`). One of the issues we encountered is integration of Functions with AppInsights. We have a custom configuration for such integration. What we want to achieve is

1. to add some custom dimensions to logs
2. to not log exceptions in certain cases

In order to do this I configure AppInsights with custom *TelemetryInitializer* and *TelemetryProcessor*. This works fine for traces and dependencies (i.e. custom dimensions are enriched with my custom key-value pairs). But it doesn't work for exceptions: they never end up in my *TelemetryProcessor* nor are their logs in AI complemented with my custom dimensions.

Here is a list of NuGet packages used in our project:

```
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.18.0"
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.5.1"
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.2.1"
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.4"
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0"
"Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.4"
```

The code of custom initializer:

```
public class FunctionTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public FunctionTelemetryInitializer(Config config)
    {
        _location = config.Location;
        _applicationName = config.ApplicationName;
        _version = config.Version;
    }

    private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Values()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"location", _location},
            {"applicationName", _applicationName},
            {"applicationVersion", _version}
        };
    }
        
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var props = telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties;
        foreach (var kvp in Values())
        {
            if (!props.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
            {
                props[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code of custom processor:

```
public class FunctionsTelemetryProcessor : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor _next;

    public FunctionsTelemetryProcessor(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
        
    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (item is TraceTelemetry trace)
        {
            if (trace.Message.Contains("Hello"))
                return;        //here I have breakpoint 1
        }
            
        if (item is ExceptionTelemetry exception)
        {
            //here I have breakpoint 2
            var retryException =
                    exception.ExceptionDetailsInfoList.FirstOrDefault(s =>
                        s.TypeName.Contains(nameof(FunctionsRetryException)));
            if (retryException != null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        _next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

Function code:

```
[Function("Test")]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("test", Connection = "Connection")]
    string message, FunctionContext context)
    {
        //when this line of code is uncommented, the breakpoint 1 in the processor is successfully hit
        //_logger.LogError("Hello!");

        //when the line above is commented out, the breakpoint 2 in the processor should be hit, but it's not
        throw new FunctionsRetryException("Test!!!");
    }
```

Program code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build()
                    .Get<FunctionsConfig>();
                    
                services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, FunctionTelemetryInitializer>();
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<FunctionsTelemetryProcessor>();

                services.AddSingleton<Config>(config);
            })
            .Build();

            return host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "never",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Warning",
      "Function": "Warning",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 20,
        "excludedTypes": "Request;Dependency;Exception"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout" : "00:05:00",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 3,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3741) and [this PR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/2657)

Comment: @PeterBons I'm not 100% sure if it's relevant. 
First, my custom TelemetryProcessor seems to be used actually. It is definitely called for certain telemetry items, e.g. traces and dependencies. It's only in case of exceptions it's not used for some unknown reason. 
Second, the PR you shared is in azure-webjobs-sdk repo. This is the repo for in-process Functions. While out-of-process Functions are here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker (I've created an issue here, though without any feedback).

Comment: This is already an open issue on GitHub [Exceptions are not cought by custom TelemetryProcesor in AppInsights](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/615)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT 
It was me who submitted an issue in the repo. After nobody has reacted on it there during a few days, I decided to ask here. 
But thanks for suggestion to use Microsoft support channels! Will try there.